# How to validate to allow only current and next date in the date picker using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two date pickers one to select the start date and the other for end date.Now I need to validate so that the user can only select current and next date from the date picker and not the other dates.How to validate using javascript

Answer (score 0):

If its about jQuery UI Datepicker, you can provide date selection range as:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1D" });
```

In this `minDate : 0` represents `Today` and `maxDate: +1D` is `Tomorrow`

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/1431/) for your requirement.

Comment: i am not using jquery datepicker

Comment: The how do people will know what you are using? Atleast you should have posted your code in your question. It will save lot of time of others to understand.

Comment: there is no code i am using a datepicker where i can select the dates

Comment: only when user is selecting the dates other than current and next date, should validate using js

Comment: "Without code nothing will work!", you must be having some js included within your code. Please provide that link which library you have used. I'm dammn sure you didn't have coded "Datepicker" for yourself!!!

Comment: Oh god!! You could have mentioned your framework detail earlier! Like this how could people can answer?

Comment: sorry about it can you tell how to validate

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. "Click edit button" on the question and provide details about your datepicker, code how you placed in web-page and framework detail as well. Don't forget to add proper tags (framework name, language you are using etc.)